# variable argument function in C

Tags: c++, c

I have a variable list function

```
/* vsprintf example */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdarg.h>

 void PrintFError (char * format, ...)
 {
    char buffer[50];
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vsprintf (buffer,format, args);
    perror (buffer);
    va_end (args);
 }

 int main ()
 {
     FILE * pFile;
     char szFileName[]="myfile.txt";
     int firstchar = (int) '#';

     pFile = fopen (szFileName,"r");
     if (pFile == NULL)
        PrintFError ("Error opening '%s'",szFileName);
     else
     {
        // file successfully open
        fclose (pFile);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

In above example how can we check the received message in "PrintError" function that we are not crossing the buffer size in this example 50 while using "vsprintf" in above example.
This should be achieved in portable way.

Comment: Or vfprintf followed by perror( NULL )

Comment: If you need to just print the message (and not save it in some variables) use `vprintf` (or `vfprintf` if you want to print on standard error or other files) instead of `vsprintf`: it will directly print the error, instead of saving it in a variable.

Comment: And note that if vsprintf sets errno, then your error message will be inappropriate.

Comment: Why put the C++ tag on this question? C and C++ are completely different languages.

Comment: @Binary Worrier:  Because such functions are valid in C++, although they're much less necessary and generally discouraged.

Comment: @Binary, tags are the the benefit of future searchers, and someone might come along in the future wanting to do the same in C++. Of course, if the original question was about C++ I'd be inclined to suggest boost::format rather than vsnprintf...

Comment: @David,@bdnolan: Hmmmm ... I see what you're saying, but still I think it should be either one or the other. C++ was based on C, so has many similar mechanisms. There once was a large amount of overlap. However as the languages evolved the area of overlap has decreased. All too often questions are posted with C & C++ tags where you can tell from the question that it applies only to one or the other. If the asker is writing this code in C++ then it should have the C++ tag. If they're writing in C it should have the C tag (IMHO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the safer vsnprintf, and limit it to 50 characters maximum.

```
int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to worry about buffer overflow.  You can't do this with vsprintf, but you *can* with [vsnprintf](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=vsnprintf), which includes an argument which is the length of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vsnprintf](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=vsnprintf). This is, strictly speaking, non-standard unless you have a C99 compiler, but is supported on most environments. If you do not have an implementation of `vsnprintf` on your platform, you can simply add a [portable implementation](http://www.jhweiss.de/software/snprintf.html) to your program.

Comment: is it posisble to do in portable way

Comment: C99 is a ratified standard, so vsnprintf is, strictly speaking, standard.

Comment: @Steve, I suppose, but the kinds of compilers that, in C89, would not have implemented vsnprintf, probably haven't gotten around to implementing C99 today.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`vsnprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vprintf.html). It allows you to specify the number of characters to output (`n`):

```
int vsnprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, va_list ap);
```